# DUPLICATION FINDING FOR ROW BASE ON COLUMN

Tags: python, django, pandas

Looking at the table in the image we could see that the row for SNO 1 with Reference number PAP123 is a duplicate of the row for SNO 3 with Reference number PAP123. We could see that the duplication happens in the CUTTING column and that is why under the DUPLICATION column for both SNO 1 and SNO 3 there is a "True" condition and in parentheses the CERTIFICATE No. and BATCH for its duplicate is indicated together with the column in which the duplicate is happening. We could also see that under the WEEDING column duplication happens for SNO 2 and SNO 4 but it is not marked as duplicate because the REFERENCE NO. are not the same. Now I want to use this same logic to modify the code below so that the output will look for duplicates like in the table of the image. For duplicate to happen a row needs to have at least a column value repeated and the value should fall under the same column. Also, the Reference no. for both rows should be the same.[image]

```
duplicate_mask = combined_data.duplicated(subset=[
                'SLASHING BEFORE LINING & PEGGING', 'CUTTING OF PEGS', 'LINING & PEGGING',
                'PLANTAIN /ECO TREE-HOLING', 'COCOA-HOLING', 'PLANTAIN /ECO TREE-PLANTING',
                'COCOA-PLANTING', 'Portage of plantain seedlings'
            ], keep=False)

            for index, row in combined_data.iterrows():
                same_values = combined_data[
                    (combined_data['SLASHING BEFORE LINING & PEGGING'] == row['SLASHING BEFORE LINING & PEGGING']) &
                    (combined_data['CUTTING OF PEGS'] == row['CUTTING OF PEGS']) &
                    (combined_data['LINING & PEGGING'] == row['LINING & PEGGING']) &
                    (combined_data['PLANTAIN /ECO TREE-HOLING'] == row['PLANTAIN /ECO TREE-HOLING']) &
                    (combined_data['COCOA-HOLING'] == row['COCOA-HOLING']) &
                    (combined_data['PLANTAIN /ECO TREE-PLANTING'] == row['PLANTAIN /ECO TREE-PLANTING']) &
                    (combined_data['COCOA-PLANTING'] == row['COCOA-PLANTING']) &
                    (combined_data['Portage of plantain seedlings'] == row['Portage of plantain seedlings'])
                ]

                same_farm_ref = same_values[same_values['FARM REF NUMBER'] == row['FARM REF NUMBER']]

                if len(same_farm_ref) > 1:
                    certs = '/'.join(str(cert) for cert in combined_data.loc[same_values, 'CERT NUMBER'])
                    batches = '/'.join(str(batch) for batch in combined_data.loc[same_values, 'Batch'])
                    combined_data.loc[index, 'Duplicates'] = f"True({certs}/{batches})"
                else:
                    false_value = False
                    combined_data.loc[index, 'Duplicates'] = false_value
```

Comment: maybe you should use `groupby(columns)` to group rows with the same values - but it may need to run separately `groupby(['REFERENCE NO", "SLASHING"])`, later `groupby(['REFERENCE NO", "CUTTING"])`, later `groupby(['REFERENCE NO", "WEEDING"])`, etc.

Comment: @furas can you please explain a little further about what you have written